# How can I delete your Node by putting your Node number?

Tags: java, data-structures

```
 public void DeleteLine(int linenum) {
    NodeLine newLine = new NodeLine();
    if (linenum < 1) {
        System.out.print("\nposition should be >= 1.");
        return;
    }
    if (firstLine == newLine) {
        firstLine = newLine.getNextLine();
    if (newLine.getNextLine() != null)
        newLine.getNextLine().setPrevLine(newLine.getPrevLine());
    if (newLine.getPrevLine() != null)
        newLine.getPrevLine().setNextLine(newLine.getNextLine());
    }
    }
```

> How can I delete your Node by putting your Node number?
> [image]

delete in doubly linked list

> delete in doubly linked list

Comment: Can you add more information like the NodeLine class, constraints, what have you tried already, etc.

Answer (score 0):

first of all , you can't initialize the head of your linked list in the delete function as the statement `NodeLine newLine = new NodeLine();` must be in the constructor not in the delete function as this line will create new empty list every time you delete , there are many modification in this linked list , I will the one I think it will work & you can compare my code to yours and if you didn't understand something from my code , you can ask me
note , this code was written using IntelliJ IDEA :

```
package com.example.test;

class Node {
    private int Val;
    private Node next;
    private Node previous;

    public Node(int val) {
        Val = val;
        next = null;
        previous = null;
    }

    public int getVal() {
        return Val;
    }

    public void setVal(int val) {
        Val = val;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public void setPrevious(Node previous) {
        this.previous = previous;
    }
}

class DoublelinkedList {
    private Node head;
    private int size;

    public DoublelinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public Node getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public void setHead(Node head) {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public void insertAtEnd(int val) {
        Node temp = new Node(val);
        size++;
        if (head == null) {
            this.head = temp;
        } else {
            Node t = this.head;
            while (t.getNext() != null){
                t = t.getNext();
            }
            t.setNext(temp);
            temp.setPrevious(t);
        }
    }
    public void DeleteLine(int nodeNum) {
        if (nodeNum < 1) {
            System.out.print("\nposition should be >= 1.");
            return;
        }
        //make sure the node number is already present
        if(nodeNum > size) {
            System.out.println("index is out of range");
        } else {
            size--;

            //corner case when deleting head node
            if(nodeNum == 1){
                Node t = head;
                head = head.getNext();
                head.setPrevious(null);
                t.setNext(null);
                return;
            }

            //get the node that you want to delete
            Node tobeDeleted = head;
            for(int i = 1; i < nodeNum ;i++) {
                tobeDeleted = tobeDeleted.getNext();
            }

            //storing the address of next and previous node
            Node next = tobeDeleted.getNext();
            Node previous = tobeDeleted.getPrevious();

            //deleting the node
            previous.setNext(tobeDeleted.getNext());
            //corner case when deleting last node
            if(next != null)
                next.setPrevious(tobeDeleted.getPrevious());

            tobeDeleted.setPrevious(null);
            tobeDeleted.setNext(null);

        }

    }
    public void printList(){
        Node t = head;
        while (t != null){
            System.out.print(t.getVal() + " ");
            t = t.getNext();
        }
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String\[\] args) {
        DoublelinkedList l = new DoublelinkedList();
        l.insertAtEnd(1);
        l.insertAtEnd(2);
        l.insertAtEnd(3);
        l.insertAtEnd(4);
        l.insertAtEnd(5);
        l.insertAtEnd(6);
        l.DeleteLine(3);

        l.printList();
    }
}
```